# CALayer is not positioned correctly within the View

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout, calayer

**Context**

I am using [this simple library](https://github.com/ariok/BWWalkthrough) to make an intro/walkthrough for my app (TL;DR, horizontal paging view controllers). I currently have 3 pages setup.

In the 3rd walkthrough page, I have a custom `CALayer` that animates a circle in an endless loop. I'd like to add that layer to a `UIView` in order to lay it out the way I want in IB (via auto layout).

In `viewDidLoad` (for the 3rd page) I create the circle layer and set its frame to be the same as the view I positioned, assuming the circle would be in the same spot as the view:

```
    for v:UIView in [view1!, view2!] {
        var pulse = PulseLayer()
        pulse.frame = v.frame
        pulse.cornerRadius = v.frame.width / 2.0
        pulse.masksToBounds = false
        view.layer.insertSublayer(pulse, above: v.layer)
    }
```

**Problem**

When I run the app in the iPhone 6 simulator, the CALayers show up OUTSIDE their UIViews (see below).

[image: CALayers misplaced]

One thing I noticed immediately is the layers are not misplaced the same way--one is above its view, and the other is to the left. I am assuming this is related to the constraints on the views, but I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Equally baffling to me is that when run on the iPhone 5 simulator, the layers appear exactly as I expect them to (see below).

[image: Layers correctly placed]

I feel like I am misunderstanding some of the concepts at work here. How can I get the positioning to act the same? (Like the iPhone5 gif.)

Or, is there a better way to do what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`viewDidLoad` is too soon. Remember, `viewDidLoad` is way early; the view is not in the interface yet and nothing has its ultimate size/position. If you're going to add the layers to `view` rather than as sublayers of the little views, you will have to run your layer-creation code much later, in order to get the position right. `viewDidAppear:` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` will be safe - but of course you must use a bool flag so you don't do it too many times.

Personally I don't see why you don't add the layers to the little views. So you would just set `pulse.frame = v.bounds` and add as a sublayer to `v`, not to your `view`. It solves the positioning and gets the relationships right. And doing it in `viewDidLoad` would work, because when the views move, the layers move with them.

Comment: Thanks, call ing function in viewDidAppear solved my problem.